# Mapreduce to hbase output stuck at map 100% reduce 100%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera

I'm running a mapreduce process in order to write a file from hdfs and write to hbase.

I've simplified the process. This is the source code:

```
public class WriteHBaseDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

    private static Configuration conf = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int exitCode;
        try {
            exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WriteHBaseDriver(), args);
            System.exit(exitCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
        conf = HBaseConfig.getConfiguration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, WriteHBaseDriver.class.getSimpleName());
            job.setJarByClass(WriteHBaseDriver.class);
            job.setMapperClass(WriteHBaseMapper.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
            job.setReducerClass(WriteHBaseReducer.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "NAMESPACE_NAME:TABLE_NAME");
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/myuser/data/input/"));
            job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return 0;


    }

    public class WriteHBaseMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,IntWritable> {

@Override
public void map(LongWritable offset, Text record, Context context) throws IOException {

        try {
            context.write(new Text("key"), new IntWritable(1));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public class WriteHBaseReducer extends TableReducer<Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(new Date().getTime()));
        String family = "M";
        String qualifier = "D";
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), Bytes.toBytes("value"));

        context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("NAMESPACE_NAME:TABLE_NAME")), put);
    }
}
```

the cluster is a recently installed cloudera cluster CHH 5.9.0 with one master node and 4 region servers
Only one zookeeper server installed on the master node.

when running the process with hadoop jar everything seems to work fine.
But when the process is at map 100% and reduce 100% it gets stuck and nothing is written to hbase.

No failure messages are shown and the only error message that I can find is:

> 2016-11-21 12:52:23,584 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator: Failed
>   verification of hbase:meta,,1 at
>   address=mdmtsthfs1.corp.ute.com.uy,60020,1479743178098,
>   exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region
>   hbase:meta,,1 is not online on
>   mdmtsthfs1.corp.ute.com.uy,60020,1479743524683
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2921)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1053)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegionInfo(RSRpcServices.java:1333)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AdminProtos$AdminService$2.callBlockingMethod(AdminProtos.java:22233)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2170)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:185)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:165)

Not even know whether it has to do with it.

what I'm missing here?

Found that error trace from zookeeper:

```
    2016-11-22 15:21:02,882 INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-11-22 15:21:02,883 WARN [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2016-11-22 15:21:02,983 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper getData failed after 4 attempts
2016-11-22 15:21:02,983 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x4e90b4f40x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/meta-region-server
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getData(ZKUtil.java:623)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.getMetaRegionState(MetaTableLocator.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.getMetaRegionLocation(MetaTableLocator.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:629)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
2016-11-22 15:21:02,984 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x4e90b4f40x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getData(ZKUtil.java:623)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.getMetaRegionState(MetaTableLocator.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.getMetaRegionLocation(MetaTableLocator.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:629)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: is sample mapreduce job working ? check enough memory is available

Comment: Any mapreduce that writes to hdfs is working. Mapreduce examples and our mapreduce processes.

Comment: Only the one that tries to write to hdfs gets stuck at map 100% reduce 100%

Comment: Make sure you use the correct version of API as the HBase version running in the your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Its' solved.

zookeeper quorum and zookeeper client port have to be set.

```
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",<ips list>);
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort",<port>);
```

Not sure why this configuration is not being taken directly from hbase-site.
Note that the process runs ok on a quickstart, but it did'n run on the recently installed cluster.
Now, setting those properties everything is fine.
thanks a lot